# How do hard reset an iPhone 8 +

Tags: iphone, restart

I googled the same question and found instructions that said press volume up, volume down then hold the power button. The problem I have is it just gets the off button. What I want is more details e.g. how long should I wait, how quick does the button press need to be, any other tricks

[image]

Note the photo was taken on an android due to iPhone issues

Answer (score 1):

The instructions outlined in the screenshot are pretty much spot on. However, the *missing* bit from your point of view relates to Step 3.

Basically, you need to keep the power button down for about 10 seconds before the iPhone will reboot. You can let go once you see the Apple logo.

Comment: Will you see the off swipe button, then the apple icon or will it go straight to the apple icon?

Comment: You will see the off swipe button first. Just ignore that and keep the power button down until you see the Apple logo.